# How can I ask the home office to send my husband's passport back before they do it?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration

I recently sent my application to the home office  for a resident card as the family member of an Eu citizen , but my husband has to go on business trip and now we need his Passport. The company bought his ticket already. Any idea how can I and where can I ask for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but it might involve having to cancel your application, and you also may lose the application fee. The normal time it takes for them to get back to you is quoted as 'within ten working days'.

How you apply depends on whether or not you applied from inside or outside the UK. Inside the UK involves an online form, if you applied outside the UK you should contact the visa application centre you used to apply.

Details of both methods can be found on the [official website](https://www.gov.uk/visa-documents-returned).